# Creating Criteria Query for combine column IN query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am stuck with this problem
I want to create Criteria Query which translates to

```
select * from table
where (col1,col2) in ((val1,val2),(val2,val3),....)
```

I understood how to create it for IN clause on single column
But I want to have IN clause on combination of two columns where values in IN clause is list of tuple of values for these two columns.

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 1):

```
EntityManager entityManager;
    
public List<YourEntity> getEntitiesByParams(Map<Field1Class, Field2Class> params) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<YourEntity> query = cb.createQuery(YourEntity.class);
    Root<YourEntity> root = query.from(YourEntity.class);

    final List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Entry<Field1Class, Field2Class> entry : params.entrySet()) {
        Predicate predicate1 = cb.equal(root.get("field1"), params.getKey());
        Predicate predicate2 = cb.equal(root.get("field2"), params.getValue());

        predicates.add(
             cb.and(predicate1, predicate2)
        );
    }

    query.select(root)
         .where(
              cb.or(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]))
         );
    
    return entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
}
```

Comment: very much appreciate quick response :) I will check this and let you know